# How to use filenames from csv-files as table names in sqlite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to import eight csv-files as separate tables into a sqlite database using python. The name of the database table should be the same as the name of the csv-file (minus the .csv-extension). How do I create tables with the same name as the csv-files and how do I insert data in the right database table?

Here is my attempt at coding this. Import statements, the UnicodeDictReader function and the connection to the database is omitted.

```
filmappe = '../csv'
for csvfile in os.listdir(filmappe):
    with open(os.path.join(filmappe, csvfile), 'rb') as fil:
        spamreader = UnicodeDictReader(fil)
        t = (csvfile[:-4],)
        to_db = [(i['fnr'], i['kjonn'], i['landbakgrunn'], i['alder'], i['arbkomm'], i['naring']) for i in spamreader]
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (fnr, kjonn, landbakgrunn, alder, arbkomm, naring);", t )
        cur.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ? (fnr, kjonn, landbakgrunn, alder, arbkomm, naring) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);",t, to_db)
```

Comment: Does the `CREATE TABLE` statement work?

Comment: @Tichodroma I get a sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?"  on the CREATE TABLE STATEMENT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a tablename as a query parameter; that is one of the *points* of using SQL parameters, prevent that data is interpreted as an object name.

You'll have to use string interpolation here instead:

```
cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "{}"
    (fnr, kjonn, landbakgrunn, alder, arbkomm, naring)
    """.format(t))
cur.executemany("""
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "{}" (fnr, kjonn, landbakgrunn, alder, arbkomm, naring)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
    """.format(t), to_db)
```

I added `"` quotes around the table name to make sure that names that are also keywords can still be used.

Do **not** do this with user-provided data; if you cannot trust the filenames, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I think because we use python 2.6.6 I got a `ValueError: zero length field name in format`, but inserting a zero in `"{}"` like this `"{0}"` seems to get rid of this error.

Comment: @Håvard: indeed; I keep forgetting to add indices as they are redundant in 2.7 and up.